# RuntimeError: The Session graph is empty. Add operations to the graph before calling run()

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am training a neural network with keras, and since my dataset is very large I am using `fit_generator` to feed the data to the network.
As the first argument of `fit_generator` I have to provide a generator that generates patches of data to my model.
I use `tf.data.Dataset` in order to make a dataset and feed the network using `make_one_shot_iterator` and calling `get_next` method.
Here is the code

```
def generator():
    dataset_iterator = DatasetGenerator(...)  # defined class to returns a tf iterator
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        next_batch = dataset_iterator.get_next()

        while True:
            img, label = sess.run(next_batch)
            # some process on label
            yield img, label


# down in the code for training:
model.fit_generator(generator=generator(), ...)
```

This works perfectly fine.
The problem begins when I try to send `dataset_iterator` as the argument to the `generator` method, like this:

```
def generator(dataset_iterator):
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        next_batch = dataset_iterator.get_next()

        while True:
            img, label = sess.run(next_batch)
            # some process on label
            yield img, label


# down in the code for training:
dataset_iterator = DatasetGenerator(...)
model.fit_generator(generator=generator(dataset_iterator), ...)
```

Now, I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: The Session graph is empty.  Add operations to the graph before calling run().
```

Comment: Add the `next_batch = dataset_iterator.get_next()` line before creating  `tf.Session()`  so that it is included in the graph and the graph does not go empty.

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal Thanks for your reply. It didn't help though. Same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to handle it.
What I found out was that printing `tf.get_default_graph()` in `generator` method and in main method (I mean before calling `model.fit_generator`) returns different graphs.

Why? I have no idea!

Anyway, I solved it by sending default graph as another argument to the function and introducing it to `tf.Session()`. Like this:

```
def generator(dataset_iterator, default_graph):
    with tf.Session(graph=default_graph) as sess:
        next_batch = dataset_iterator.get_next()

        while True:
            img, label = sess.run(next_batch)
            # some process on label
            yield img, label


# down in the code for training:
dataset_iterator = DatasetGenerator(...)
default_graph = tf.get_default_graph()
model.fit_generator(generator=generator(dataset_iterator, default_graph), ...)
```

I actually don't know if this is the most elegant way to solve the problem. Further improvements are greatly appreciated :)

Comment: This fixed a related problem I had where I was trying to keep a session alive across multiple invocations of a function. But without creating a default graph outside the session creation it crashed with the same message. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score -1):

It's eager execution, disable it if you want to create an empty session.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. I see that you are a new contributor, so here is a request: your answer is lacking some explanation, could you edit it explaining why disabling the eager execution could solve the issue ? To make is even better, you could add a snippet informing how to do it.