# Adding two numbers by using Tensorflow 2 and Python 3.7?

Tags: tensorflow

Running the following simple code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
#%%
a=tf.Variable(1, name="a")
b=tf.Variable(2, name="b")
f=a+b
init=tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.compat.v1.Session() as s:
    s.run(int)
    print(f.eval())
```

gives this error: 
RuntimeError: The Session graph is empty.  Add operations to the graph before calling run().

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Have you search Internet for the error? Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54404821/runtimeerror-the-session-graph-is-empty-add-operations-to-the-graph-before-cal) helps?

Comment: Or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42593771/session-graph-is-empty) ?

Comment: Also, you may want to explain where your code is adapted from... so that people can see the difference between your code and the template you used.

Comment: This is the original code I got from a training Youtube video for tensorflow

import tensorflow as tf

a=tf.Variable(1, name="a")
b=tf.Variable(2, name="b")
f=a+b
init=tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session as s:
    init.run(f.eval8()

Comment: Don't write that in the comments. You can edit your question instead :) And add a link to the video. Note that you can tag code like so `\`some short code\`` or by letting 4 spaces in front of a line.

Comment: Just a thought, but if you plan on learning modern TensorFlow 2.x more generally, you might want to find a more recent tutorial. Things have changed quite a bit since the TensorFlow 1.x style of code you use above.

Answer (score 2):

In tensorflow 2.0 you don't need to create the session. 
If you'd like to print the value of `f` you can just write

```py
tf.print(f)
```

Or if you'd like to assign value to the variable you can write

```py
new_value = f.numpy()
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
#%%
graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
  a=tf.Variable(1, name="a")
  b=tf.Variable(2, name="b")
  init=tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer()
  f=a+b


with tf.compat.v1.Session(graph = graph) as s:
    s.run(init)
    print(f.eval())
```

If you want to use TensorFlow V1.X, you need to construct a graph that basically lines up all the operations and the flow of your data. Then you pass that graph to a session and you will run the session.

Here is a good intro I found: https://www.easy-tensorflow.com/tf-tutorials/basics/graph-and-session

Another thing I noticed about your code is that you initialized your variables after you used them to calculate `f`. This should come before.
So I changed that as well.
Lastly, you wrote `s.run(**int**)` while I think you meant `s.run(**init**)`. So I changed that as well.